# How to assign cells (Mapping data) from Google Sheets by I2 Localization in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-sheets, localization

Before using I2 Localization I used to download data from .csv file from a remote computer. It doesn't really work as I want to.

I downloaded data from .csv, next divide by lines and assign as array string then I divide data as columns by `;` mark. So that allowed me to make GameObjects in an array which have some features and after that allowed me to call some specific object which has some feature that I want to find and display.

So, that is how I want to use I2 Localization. I connected I2loc with Google Sheets by I2languages.prefab > spreadsheet> (and connect with Google). 
That is done.

How can I download data line by line and assign to variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

```
print(LocalizationManager.Sources[0].mTerms[4].Languages[3]);

LocalizationManager.Sources[0] - means source files
.mTerms[iteration] - means which line u want take 
.Languages[iteration] - means what exacly column u want to choose
```

That let us to assign data from Spreadsheet to a variable.